# What are the best solutions for flash charts and graphs?

Tags: flash, graph

I'm aware of [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/), are there other good solutions, or APIs, for creating charts in Adobe Flash?

Comment: Would you prefer FusionCharts Free over Open-FLash-Chart or the other way around and why? FusionCharts looks a bit nicer ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is there a reason that you want it in Flash? If a plain, old PNG will work, try the [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/).

Comment: There's also a nice .NET warpper library to Google CHart API and it'll save your server a lot of job http://code.google.com/p/googlechartsharp/

Comment: I worked with it and found it too limitated for complex graphs

Answer (score 10):

http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/ seems really sweet. I suggest you give it a look.

UPDATE: Open Flash Chart 2 is out: http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/

Comment: it doesn't only seem sweet, open-flash-chart 2 IS sweet a.k.a. great, flexible, has libraries for js, php, ruby, python, perl, etc. etc. and uses JSON and is therefore AJAX compatible!!!!!

Comment: You can resize charts which is nice. Export them to .png (via base64) into a javascript object and display them. Do all sorts of cool things.

Answer (score 10):

Depending on your needs, a couple others you might look at:

**Flare**

[image: flare]

**Prefuse**

[image: prefuse]

Comment: Dude. Crazy. I know it is wrong, but I want to make up a report just to use these visualizations.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best Flash charts are [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com) - nice looking, highly customizable and free (if you don't mind the link back to amcharts.com)

Answer (score 2):

XML/SWF Charts does Chart off XML:

http://www.maani.us/xml_charts/

Answer (score 2):

I know you said flash, but this is a good silverlight chart api. http://www.visifire.com/. Always good to keep your options open right?

Had to plug silverlight, but you can also take a look at [Yahoo!'s YUI charting](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/charts/) component.

Answer (score 2):

[open-flash-chart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/) because you can't resize a .png and .png has no tooltips. Also why would you send all your data to google? Do you trust them that much?

Answer (score 1):

I can vouch that I've had good experiences with [PHP/SWF charts](http://www.maani.us/charts/index.php) (and by extension, the XML/SWF charts too). It's easy to create really subtle chart effects. Pie charts fading in one slice at a time looks fairly professional without being annoying.

Edit: Scratch that, [Open-Flash-Chart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/) looks WAY better. I recede my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe's data visualization package is now free after the release of Flash Builder 4.

Charting and other libraries are on this site - http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+4

Answer (score 0):

MultiChart, because it beats all the others in all parameters.
http://chart.sqlcode.org